# Logic with degrees of inconsistency between two statements

Tags: first-order-logic, modal-logic

Does somebody know a logic with some modal operator $\sim$, where a **degree of inconsistency** between two statements $\sim ( \phi(x) = a ) $ and $\sim( \phi(x) = b) $ is a monotonous function $f: |a - b| \rightarrow R^+, \; f(0) = 0$?

The modal operator $\sim$  may be interpreted as "It appears". The logic would be great to formalize machine learning.

Would you have objections against such logic if it is proposed?